# Is there a way to pass Jenkins credentials to automation test execution command?

Tags: powershell, jenkins, protractor

I have created some global credentials in Jenkins, and I want to pass them to a powershell command that starts the execution of a protractor test suite.
The credentials are created properly, the bindings are also done as you can see int he image below:

[image]

The thing is, I need these credentials to use them when running the automation tests. The powershell command that I execute is the next one:

```
npm run test -- --userName=${env:ECASUSER} --password=${env:ECASPWD}
```

After I start the job the command is called inside the windows agent as expected, triggering the tests. When the test are using those credentials to authenticate it seems they are empty strings.
In the job console log, both credentials appear to be there but displayed like this (****).

I have tried a lot of solution none of them work. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Wait, what is your problem again? that credentials are shown as ******? this is expected, jenkins masks them, this is a feature of jenkins credentials so noone can access it

Comment: This is not the issue, the issue is that in the tests, those credentials are blank. So the test are failing because the authentication doesn't work. I understand that jenkins masks them for security reasons, but it should pass the credentials to the tests, no?

Comment: Just add each variable as secret text instead. And then you just access it like `--username=${ECAUSER}`.

Comment: Apparently, for poweshell plugin, you need to add 'env:' in front of binding variables. Otherwise they will be ignored. I have added more details in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

After some time spent to this, I reached the conclusion that this never worked. Or maybe it did at some point but, yeah it simply stopped.
Basically, Jenkins is not passing credentials to Windows batch or Power shell commands. My automation tests were running on blanks.

The only solution, that I found to this problem, is this one:

1. Create a new binding: Username and Password(conjoined) - here create a new job parameter containing the credentials. Let's say the parameter is named USERPASS;
2. Create a new 'Windows batch command' section where you save the credentials to a file in you test project (amazingly this one works) - your credentials will be saved to the file like this: "username:password". This is how you save the credentials:

   echo %USERPASS% > "%WORKSPACE%\password.txt"
3. Change the automation test project to retrieve the credentials from the file;
4. Delete the file after the tests are completed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should have been

```
npm run test --userName=${ECASUSER} --password=${ECASPWD}
```

and make sure you don't pass unnecessary `--`

Let me know if that doesn't work, I have other ideas

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately, '--' needs to be there otherwise the I will receive invalid argument error. Those two dashes are there to call the project's 'config' file where the variables that I want to initialize, are defined. Related to not using 'env:', this also doesn't work. Binding variables need the 'env:' in front. This is specific to Jenkins 'Windows Powershell Script' plugin. As an example: when I do a "echo ${env:ECASUSER}", in the job execution logs I receive "****" which means that the username is retrieved but is masked. Not using 'env:' will output nothing.

Comment: okay, I never used windows powershell, so pardon for confusions. Essentially you need to break your problem into different layers and find where this goes wrong. First layer does jenkins pass a variable? having ***** doesn't mean it passes the right credentials. in fact, it masks EVERYTHING, so if it has empty string, it will also be ***** (I think). Next layer, does npm pass credentials to protraxctor. This is better to try locally, run npm run test --userName=username --password=Password123 and see if protractor can login. Etc until you find where the error happens

Comment: I have tried it. First, I have executed the tests locally by adding the credentials in the command. It works OK. Then I have tried it from Jenkins, with the same command with inline credentials. It didn't work. I got the same behavior: login fails with empty username and password.
At this point I am out of ideas.

Comment: try to log credentials somehow. Sounds like jenkins doesn't pickup the right pair